# Fetch distinct available dates from table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a data table where data is present for every date (for 50 branches) except saturday and sunday. I am trying to get the last valid date from table from multiple given dates.

```
select distinct BW_DATE from backdated_weekly where BW_DATE <='2021-09-30' or BW_DATE<='2021-09-26' order by BW_DATE desc;
```

As 2021-09-30 is a valid date but 2021-09-26 (Sunday) is not present in table. I am trying to get output as

```
2021-09-30
2021-09-24
```

But above query gives all results below given dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is confirmed there are dates continuously in the table for all mon-fri only, simply select the maximum date up to the given date

```
SELECT MAX(BW_DATE)
FROM backdated_weekly
WHERE BW_DATE <= '2021-09-30'
UNION
SELECT MAX(BW_DATE)
FROM backdated_weekly
WHERE BW_DATE <= '2021-09-26'
```

Also we can calculate newest date in mon-fri for a given date directly without any table

[`WEEKDAY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday) is the function to be used

> Returns the weekday index for date (0 = Monday, 1 = Tuesday, … 6 =
> Sunday).

```
SELECT CASE WHEN WEEKDAY('2021-09-30') IN ( 5, 6 ) THEN DATE('2021-09-30') - INTERVAL WEEKDAY('2021-09-30') - 4 DAY ELSE DATE('2021-09-30') END
UNION
SELECT CASE WHEN WEEKDAY('2021-09-26') IN ( 5, 6 ) THEN DATE('2021-09-26') - INTERVAL WEEKDAY('2021-09-26') - 4 DAY ELSE DATE('2021-09-26') END
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=477775c0eddbfa733e60bc629a8a68d4

Comment: SELECT MAX(BW_DATE)
FROM backdated_weekly
WHERE BW_DATE <= '2021-9-30'
UNION
SELECT MAX(BW_DATE)
FROM backdated_weekly
WHERE BW_DATE <= '2021-8-31'
UNION
SELECT MAX(BW_DATE)
FROM backdated_weekly
WHERE BW_DATE <= '2021-7-31'
UNION
SELECT MAX(BW_DATE)
FROM backdated_weekly
WHERE BW_DATE <= '2021-6-30'
UNION
SELECT MAX(BW_DATE)
FROM backdated_weekly
WHERE BW_DATE <= '2021-5-31'
UNION
SELECT MAX(BW_DATE)
FROM backdated_weekly
WHERE BW_DATE <= '2021-4-30' I used above query but it almost takes 5 to 6 seconds to fetch the data, which is too high. Any solution?

Comment: it looks you are getting last working day for each month? try this `SELECT MAX(BW_DATE), LAST_DAY(MAX(BW_DATE))
FROM backdated_weekly
WHERE BW_DATE BETWEEN '2021-04-01' AND '2021-09-30'
GROUP BY YEAR(BW_DATE), MONTH(BW_DATE)`

Comment: @erdeepak
 it's better to add index for BW_DATE